# What design pattern to implement in order to use a REST API?

Tags: java, design-patterns, api, oop, rest

I'm starting a new project that will require use an external REST API that basically returns JSON and XML files. It's similar to the [StackExchange API](http://stackapps.com) and I see every wrapper that has be done for that API has a different approach; for instance, [stackoverflow-java-sdk](https://stackapps.com/questions/236/stackoverflow-java-sdk-java-wrapper-for-stackexchange-api) uses the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

So, in order to make sure every new API feature will be included easyly... what would be the best design pattern?

Comment: Why do you *need* a design pattern?

Comment: Nice question... there are people who consider that a design pattern could be handy to do a more mantainable software... on the other hand other people think they are not useful at all. I just want to apply it to see if they really are as nice as some say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) can be used to encapsulate two interfaces so they can vary independently.  Sounds like what you're interested in.